# How to use twitter Oauth get request in php and zend framework to retrieve some user data

Tags: php, zend-framework, twitter, oauth, controller

I had a small problem in using twitter oauth in order to get some user data.

```
// TWITTER APP KEYS
    $consumer_key = 'some data';
    $consumer_secret = 'some data';

    // GETTING ALL THE TOKEN NEEDED
    $oauth_verifier = $_GET['oauth_verifier'];
    $token_secret = $_COOKIE['token_secret'];
    $oauth_token = $_COOKIE['oauth_token'];

    // EXCHANGING THE TOKENS FOR OAUTH TOKEN AND TOKEN SECRET
    $connection = new TwitterOAuth($consumer_key, $consumer_secret, $oauth_token, $token_secret);
    $access_token = $connection->oauth("oauth/access_token", array(
        "oauth_verifier" => $oauth_verifier
    ));

    $accessToken = $access_token['oauth_token'];
    $secretToken = $access_token['oauth_token_secret'];

    $connection = new TwitterOAuth($consumer_key, $consumer_secret, $accessToken, $secretToken);
    $connection->get("users/search");
    $content = $connection->get("account/verify_credentials");
    $media1 = $connection->upload('media/upload', [
        'media' => $this->session->image['generatedAbs']
    ]);
    $parameters = [
        'media_id' => implode(',', [
            $media1->media_id_string
        ])
    ];
    $result = $connection->post('account/update_profile_banner', $parameters);
```

now I want to retrieve some information like the name and last name of the connected user , his profile picture link , email adress and his location  if it's possible 
I read the official [twitter dev documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/users/show) and i didn't find a way how to use it in my method , i tried to debug my controller using this way

```
$connection = new TwitterOAuth($consumer_key, $consumer_secret, $accessToken, $secretToken);
    $connection->get("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/profile_banner.json?screen_name=twitterapi");
    $result = json_decode($connection);
    // debug the returned result 
    Zend_Debug::dump($result,$label="debug gass" , $echo= true);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So to retrieving information from twitter using php and Twitter Oauth is super easy , just allow me to enumerate the steps

1) Getting an oauth_token and oauth_verifier (steps are clearly explained in the question

2) The funny part is now :D , you need to copy paste the following in the controller of you callback page:

```
$connection = new TwitterOAuth($consumer_key, $consumer_secret, $accessToken, $secretToken);
$content = $connection->get("account/verify_credentials");
```

Now you really have finished everything , just debug the result :D

```
Zend_Debug::dump($content->profile_image_url , $label = "achref gassoumi", $echo = true);
```

ps: i used zend debugger since i'm working , if you are working with other framework or with pure php just echo the following result for example :

```
echo $credentials->screen_name;
echo $credentials->profile_image_url ;
echo $credentials->location;
echo $credentials->profile_background_image_url;
```

To retrieve other information you might need please visit the official twitter Oauth documentation of [GET account/verify_credentials](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/account/verify_credentials).